# python httplib Name or service not known

Tags: python, ssl, httplib

I'm trying to use httplib to send credit card information to authorize.net.  When i try to post the request, I get the following traceback:

```
File "./lib/cgi_app.py", line 139, in run res = method()
File "/var/www/html/index.py", line 113, in ProcessRegistration conn.request("POST", "/gateway/transact.dll", mystring, headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 946, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 987, in _send_request self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 803, in _send_output self.send(msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 755, in send self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1152, in connect self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection raise error, msg
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I build my request like so:

```
mystring = urllib.urlencode(cardHash)
headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml", "Content-Length": str(len(mystring))}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("secure.authorize.net:443", source_address=("myurl.com", 443))
conn.request("POST", "/gateway/transact.dll", mystring, headers)
```

to add another layer to this, it was working on our development server which has httplib 2.6 and without the source_address parameter in httplib.HTTPSConnection.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

===========================================================

EDIT:

I can run it from command line.  Apparently this is some sort of permissions issue.  Any ideas what permissions I would need to grant to which users to make this happen?  Possibly Apache can't open the port?

Comment: What happens with a GET request, same path, no headers?

Comment: same thing as on a post.

Comment: Hm, the script works fine here, even getting to `The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.` if I print the response. Focus on network issues;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ultimately came down to the fact that selinux was stopping apache from getting that port.  Disabling selinux fixed the problems.  I had an issue later where i didn't have /var/www/.python-eggs/, so MySQLdb was hosing on import.  But after a mkdir, it was fixed.

Answer (score 19):

As an (obvious) heads up, this same error can also be triggered by including the protocol in the host parameter. For example this code:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("http://secure.authorize.net", 80, ....)
```

will also cause the "gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known" error, even if all your networking setup is correct.

Answer (score 8):

> gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

This error often indicates a failure of your DNS resolver.  Does `ping secure.authorize.net` return successful replies from the same server that receives the gaierror?  Does the hostname have a typo in it?

Comment: ping returns a "Packet filtered" message and fails.  I'd assume that this is because it is secured and will only accept port 443.  at this point I'm getting a "Permission Denied" message.  I'm not sure if that's a step forward or back.

Comment: Chris, I'm able to ping secure.authorize.net successfully.  What does `nslookup secure.authorize.net` tell you?

Comment: Server:  192.168.3.1
Address: 192.168.3.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: secure.authorize.net
Address: 64.94.118.33
Name: secure.authorize.net
Address: 64.94.118.32

Answer (score 0):

pass the port separately from the host:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("secure.authorize.net", 443, ....)
```

Comment: that returned "error: [Errno13] Permission denied"  What exactly should my source address be?  can it just me "www.mydomain.com" or should it be "http://www.mydomain.com/mypy.py"?  does it even matter?

Comment: the Permission Denied" was actually caused by me changing my source_address.  separating the url and port didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: what do you mean? Now you don't get the `gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` anymore but another error?

Comment: now i'm getting a Permission denied error.  I think apache doesn't have permission to use that port or something.

Comment: @Chris: Can you update the question with updated code and the full new error traceback?

Comment: we actually worked it out.  the code was fine.  The problem ultimately came down to the fact that selinux was stopping apache from getting that port. Disabling selinux fixed the problems. I had an issue later where i didn't have /var/www/.python-eggs/, so MySQLdb was hosing on import. But after a mkdir, it was fixed.