# http error + gaierror + ConnectionError + locust + IIS

Tags: iis, performance-testing, locust

I got the following error during stress test. I search about it but couldnt find an explanation. Does anyone know about this error?

> "ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2,
>   'Name or service not known')),)"

Comment: How are you invoking locust?

Comment: I have 6 slaves and a master. I swarm it via masters :8089 port on ui.

Comment: Right, but are you setting the host properly? Typically this happens when you try to make a request to an improperly formatted URL.

Comment: I think the host correct because this error comes very rare such as 1/10000 but confusing.

Comment: This error is propagated by httplib. Maybe you can find your answer by searching related answers? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7668559/1270148 I can't really help out with this without a lot more code. Any idea which Locust test is generating the error? Can you post the code for the problematic test?

Comment: thanks for the help this may helpful. I deleted the notes for the test, next time  I will play with the host and port then i can give more information.